# Do something while running exec

Tags: go, cmd

I don't know how to do something while running binary file.

```
cmd = exec.Command("./app-godemon-app-godemon-tmp-generated")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
fmt.Println("A")
```

The file `app-godemon-app-godemon-tmp-generated` is REST API app running on port 8000, I want to print something in command line while this API is running, but `fmt.Println()` is running only after stopping `app-godemon-app-godemon-tmp-generated` process.

Comment: This is what goroutines are for. They let you do multiple things concurrently.

Comment: I know, but i have probelm with this cuz idk where to use it in this example, could you look at my code and help me? https://github.com/nProgrammer/godemon

Comment: i want to execute this code in 67 line, while running this bin file

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
cmd = exec.Command("./app-godemon-app-godemon-tmp-generated")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
go cmd.Run()
fmt.Println("A")
```

though if your command calls depend on each other you have to add more code like

```
// call command...

    // initialize
    finish := make(chan struct{}) // i em using empty struct as data is not important
    go func() {
        // do staff...

        // finished so send signal
        finish <- struct{}{}
    }()

    //do staff...

    <-finish
    // call dependent commands, as line above halts progrum until something arrives from channel
```

you should though encapsulate this logic in function that returns channel and accepts function